# How to set instance variables in Javascript using 'this'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, oop

How do I set the class properties of the class below? The latitude and longitude of the class is still undefined after the scope of `setLatLong()`. I have tried to make variable inside the `setLatLong()`-function and returned them, but apparently I can't figure out how variables and scopes work in Javascript.

To those who want to try the link, replace this.street_name with 'hvid*' and this.zip_code with '2400'.

```
import React from "react";

class Place {
  street_name;
  zip_code;
  latitude;
  longitude;
  constructor(zip_code, street_name, latitude = 0, longitude = 0) {
    this.zip_code = zip_code;
    this.street_name = street_name;
    this.setLatLong(latitude, longitude);
  }

  setLatLong(latitude, longitude) {
    const url = `https://api.dataforsyningen.dk/adgangsadresser?q=${this.street_name}&postnr=${this.zip_code}&struktur=mini`
    if (latitude === 0 && longitude === 0) {
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => {
          let item = json[Math.floor(Math.random() * json.length)];
          this.latitude = item.y;
          this.longitude = item.x;
        })
    }
  }
}

export default Place;
```

Comment: You probably are expecting things to be set immediatelly, but since you are using the `fetch` API to make an HTTP request, the `latitude` and `longitude` members of the `Place` class are being set asynchronously.

Comment: I have also tried with async and await.
What would be a solution then?

Comment: A solution to what problem? Your code is OK. It just takes a while before `fetch` returns the properties that you want to set. Also, the properties are not set when latitude and longitude are NOT 0.

Comment: OK. How would I make sure that when I try to access the properties of the class instance somewhere else in the code, that the properties are actually set? Can I await a construction of a class object like so: ```const foo = await new Place(x,y);```

Comment: https://api.dataforsyningen.dk/adgangsadresser?q=hvid&postnr=2400&struktur=mini this url gives empty array as response, may be that was the issue since item.x and item.y is undefined

Comment: No. Try to add the exact value as described in the question. The point is not whether the response is empty or not